# Opencart 3.0.x.x storage folder

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

I'm getting below issue after installing the opencart. I have a storage folder `XAMPP/storage/` which has read and write permission.

/admin/Config.php

```
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/Applications/XAMPP/storage/');
```

**Error:**

> Warning: fopen(/Applications/XAMPP/storage/logs/error.log): Failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/crackers/system/library/log.php
> on line 22

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows:

if Storage not moved it should be defined in /admin/Config.php:

```
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/oc3.x.x.x/system/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', DIR_SYSTEM . 'storage/');
```

If you moved it to `XAMPP/storage/` accordingly should be:

```
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/oc3.x.x.x/system/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', DIR_SYSTEM . 'XAMPP/storage/');
```

It's mean that your installation of the OC are in `C:/xampp/htdocs/oc3.x.x.x` folder